# Diffusion versus dispersion

Tags: diffusion, dispersion, porous-media

What is the difference between diffusion and dispersión in porous media?

In my model mathematical,

Advection-Diffusion-Reaction Equation

Or

Advection-Dispersion-reaction Equation ?

Help please

Answer (score 0):

Diffusion refers specifically to molecular motion due to the combined effect of collisions between a particle ("solute") and the medium that surrounds it. It is described by a diffusion coefficient that depends on the size of the solute and the properties of the medium.

Dispersion is a more general term that describes the diffusion-like expansion of a sharp moving front. It may be due to several mechanisms in addition to molecular diffusion, for example complex fluid motion, eddies, flow around obstacles and so on.